# How to develop a vim plugin which is compatible with vim-plug

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm writing a simple plugin that consists of various files which I'm storing in the standard places: `.vim/ftplugin`, `.vim/plugin`, `.vim/systax`, etc. It's growing and I'd like to have all this sorted in a single repository, and eventually let it be handled by [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug).

This might be a dumb question, but how do I have to organise my files in a single folder and what line do I have to use to let vim plug handle my plugin and eventually make installable? I could not find this documented anywhere.

So far I have created the following file structure:

```
> tree ~/.vim/bundle/vim-sbatch
/home/sp4e/.vim/bundle/vim-sbatch
├── doc
├── ftplugin
│   └── sbatch.vim
├── plugin
│   └── sbatch.vim
└── syntax
    └── sbatch.vim
```

But this alone does not work. The commands defined in `.vim/plugin/sbatch` do not exist. This kind of makes sense, because I have been exploring the `'rtp'` variable and indeed there is no reference to `.vim/budle/vim-sbatch`. How do I let know vim-plug that it must look at this directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has two "runtime directories": one at the system level, in `/usr/share/vim/` (or some other place depending on your system), and one at the user level, in `~/.vim/` (or some other place, depending on your system).

Both directories are meant to have a similar structure: `autoload/`, `doc/`, `ftplugin/`, `plugin/`, etc. What we call a "plugin" can be a single file under `plugin/` or any number of files in any number of those standard directories. Hell, it could even handle its own directory structure.

Vim-plug and all the other plugin managers work the same way: they add more runtime directories, one for each "plugin", to Vim's default `:help 'runtimepath'`. Therefore, in order to make your plugin work with every current plugin management solution, all you need to do is *bundle* the directories/files that make up your plugin together in their own runtime directory.

The following procedure use the native `:help packages` feature. You should read that help section before going further.

Let's assume your plugin `foo` is currently scattered around your `~/.vim/` directory:

```
~/.vim/autoload/foo.vim
~/.vim/doc/foo.txt
~/.vim/ftplugin/foo.vim
~/.vim/syntax/foo.vim
```

1. create the necessary infrastructure for "packages":

   ```
   ~/.vim/pack/<arbitrary name>/start/
   ```
2. create a directory for your plugin:

   ```
   ~/.vim/pack/<arbitrary name>/start/foo/
   ```
3. replicate the desired structure:

   ```
   ~/.vim/pack/<arbitrary name>/start/foo/autoload/
   ~/.vim/pack/<arbitrary name>/start/foo/doc/
   ~/.vim/pack/<arbitrary name>/start/foo/ftplugin/
   ~/.vim/pack/<arbitrary name>/start/foo/syntax/
   ```
4. and, finally, move your files:

   ```
   ~/.vim/pack/<arbitrary name>/start/foo/autoload/foo.vim
   ~/.vim/pack/<arbitrary name>/start/foo/doc/foo.txt
   ~/.vim/pack/<arbitrary name>/start/foo/ftplugin/foo.vim
   ~/.vim/pack/<arbitrary name>/start/foo/syntax/foo.vim
   ```

The end result is a single directory `foo/` containing all your plugin's files, that can be put under version control and zipped for distribution.

See `:help usr_51`.

--- EDIT ---

Your question is really two questions: "How to package a custom Vim plugin?" and "How to load a custom Vim plugin with vim-plug?".

> **How to package a custom Vim plugin?**

The plugin management solution you or your would-be users use is irrelevant when it comes to packaging. You don't package a plugin in one way for vim-plug and in another way for $OTHER_PLUGIN_MANAGER. All plugin managers work the same and the expected structure is always the same. In your case, this is the structure of your plugin:

```
vim-sbatch/ftplugin/sbatch.vim
vim-sbatch/plugin/sbatch.vim
vim-sbatch/syntax/sbatch.vim
```

> **How to load a custom Vim plugin with vim-plug?**

If you use vim-plug, which I don't, then that directory can be literally anywhere on your machine:

```
~/Documents/MyProjects/sbatch/vim-sbatch
```

and either added to vim-plug with the following directive:

```
Plug '~/Documents/MyProjects/sbatch/vim-sbatch'
```

as instructed in vim-plug's documentation, or put under version control and hosted on GitHub, which lets you add it just like any other plugin:

```
Plug 'Pythonist/vim-sbatch'
```

again, as instructed in vim-plug's documentation.

Comment: Any special reason for using `~/.vim/pack/<arbitrary name>` instead of `/<arbitrary path>`? OP mentioned vim-plug and its documentation explicitly mentions the ability to pick up any local directory.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations. I have added more details to further clarify my question. The problem is that once put the files in the right places, the `'rtp'` option is not updated to account for my plugin. I guess there is something missing in my `.vimrc`.

Comment: @Friedrich, the structure of a plugin is the same no matter what so the location of its directory is irrelevant. I chose to use the built-in package feature for portability.

Comment: @Pythonist see [vim-plug's doc](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#example): `Plug '~/my-prototype-plugin'` (adapted to your path) is supposed to be in your `vimrc`. Also, did you `:PlugInstall`/`:PlugUpdate`?

Comment: @Pythonist my answer deals with bundling all the files that make up your plugin into a single directory suitable for use with any plugin manager. To make it more concrete, I used the package feature but, if you want to use a specific plugin manager, you will have to read its documentation instead of doing random things. See my edit.

Comment: Gosh, thanks for the answer and the continuous replies. Not so thanks for the tone. I'm not doing random things, I think my question was clear from the very beginning, I haven't edited the title and it's pretty clear: 2 aspects, where/how to put the files and how to tell Vim about them, specifically in vim-plug. Anyway thanks a lot. The `Plug '~/Documents/MyProjects/sbatch/vim-sbatch'` bit is exactly what I could not find in the documentation. Now, knowing was I was looking for, I could finally find it.

Comment: @Pythonist to be brutally honest, I misunderstood your question in the same way romainl did. I would have given a similar answer.